# Mysql LEFT JOIN twice using same parent primary key ON different child tables

Tags: mysql, count, left-join, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have 4 tables:
`T1 {id, user_name, email, telephone, created_at, updated_at}` 
`T2 {id, menu_name, town, district, t1_foreign, view_budget, view_menu, created_at, updated_at}` 
`T3 {id, t2_foreign, menu_item_name, ingredients, calories, cost_ex, cost_in, selling_in, selling_ex, image_dir, img_caption, view_item, created_at, updated_at}` 
`T4 {id, t1_foreign, t2_foreign, created_at, updated_at}`

A user from `T1` is linked to a menu in `T2` on `T2.t1_foreign`.  The idea was originally that only the linked user that is the rep in an area will be able to see the cost of menu items in table `T3`.  But this changed so table `T4` was created to link other users to `T2` on `T4.t2_foreign` and `T4.t1_foreign` so they will also be able to view the cost for specific menus.

I am trying to create a summary query so I can view the menu's info as well as the number of linked users, but I am getting duplicate aggregate COUNT.  I figured out that it is due to the double join with same alias for `T2`, but cannot seem to get a handle on getting around this problem.

```
SELECT t2.id t2.menu_name, t2.town, t2.district, t2.view_menu, t2.view_budget, 
IF(COUNT(t4.t2_foreign)=0, "1", CONCAT("1+", COUNT(t4.t2_foreign), " Others")) AS linked, // <=== aggregate function
GREATEST(t2.updated_at, t2.created_at, COALESCE(t3.updated_at, \'1000-01-01\'), COALESCE(t3.created_at, \'1000-01-01\')) AS newest
    FROM T2 AS t2
        LEFT JOIN T3 AS t3
            ON (t3.t2_foreign = t2.id)
        INNER JOIN T1 AS t1
            ON (t2.t1_foreign = t1.id)
        LEFT JOIN T4 AS t4
            ON (t4.t2_foreign = t2.id) // this creates duplicate count
    GROUP BY t2.id
    ORDER BY (newest, ASC)
```

I have tried a subquery join

```
SELECT t2.id t2.menu_name, t2.town, t2.district, t2.view_menu, t2.view_budget, 
tt.linked, 
GREATEST(t2.updated_at, t2.created_at, COALESCE(t3.updated_at, \'1000-01-01\'), COALESCE(t3.created_at, \'1000-01-01\')) AS newest
    FROM T2 AS t2
        LEFT JOIN T3 AS t3
            ON (t3.t2_foreign = t2.id)
        INNER JOIN T1 AS t1
            ON (t2.t1_foreign = t1.id)
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT IF(COUNT(t4.t2_foreign)=0, "1", CONCAT("1+", COUNT(t4.t2_foreign), " Others")) AS linked
                FROM T4
            ) AS t4 ON (t4.t2_foreign = t2.id) // this give not unique table/alias error
    GROUP BY t2.id
    ORDER BY (newest, ASC)
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to get the correct aggregate COUNT result?

**UPDATE : Result albeit not the expected** 
After fiddling around with my subquery effort I got it to return a result, but the result is the aggregate for all the records and not for each record. Had to change it to :

```
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT IF(COUNT(t4.t2_foreign)=0, "1", CONCAT("1+", COUNT(t4.t2_foreign), " Others")) AS linked, t4.t2_foreign
                FROM T4 as t4
            ) AS tt ON (tt.t2_foreign = t2.id)
```

On the right track though.

Comment: Either aggregate than join or use correlated subqueries.

Comment: How do I first do the aggregate and then the join?

Comment: Aggregate in the subquery, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In the end a Join was not needed, I used a correlated subquery as a sub-`SELECT` as suggested in the comments.  Subquery :

```
( SELECT IF(COUNT(t4.t2_foreign)=0, "1", CONCAT("1+", COUNT(t4.t2_foreign), " Others")) AS linked
    FROM T4 as t4
    WHERE t4.t2_foreign=t2.id
    ) AS linked
```

This retrieved an aggregate COUNT for the number of linked users in table T4 to table T2 for each primary key in T2.